# Managing intermittent data in ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder

I'm writing a model to automate combining county land cover masks in a large watershed. For example, I run Mosaic to New Raster to combine a Rail Right of Way mask (1,null) with an impervious structure mask, and an impervious Non-Road mask. Many Counties have Rail Land Cover and many others do not. Even if the Rail does not exist, I still want to mosaic any specified masks that do exist.

I know I can use "Exists" and Merge Branch, but I actually have many different classes that do not always appear in a given county, e.g. beaches, tidal wetlands, and others. It becomes onerous to write Calculate Value and Merge Branch conditions for every permutation of a set of classes existing or not. I see no way to create a "Null" or NoData Raster as dummy input.

Creating Zero rasters for each missing datatype involves huge amounts of disk space as I am working at 1 meter resolution in a very large watershed. Any idea how I can get Mosaic to Raster to go ahead and Mosaic all the existing raster input I specify and ignore those that do not exist? Does anyone know of a more or less elegant work around?